# Extracting a pattern from python string using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a string from one of the log files as below.

```
pf_string = "2018-02-01 00:54:49,285 [210.67.123.00]  [ABC,CDE,sfv4_ABC.,dbPool5,11689563,fp2871,en_US]  UNKNOWN-UNKNOWN EVENT-UNKNOWN-UNKNOWN-pc4bcf46t-20180201005446-663570 2994 770 3199 168 26 [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; ABC-IE11; rv:11.0) like Gecko]     3677610951-0 PERFORMANCE PM_REVIEW FORM_DETAIL [[95211KB 480ms 460ms 20ms 212KB 0KB 118KB 57KB 0 0 ]] 74 139 - - - -   "
```

Now I want to extract a pattern like below:

```
Module_id -> PERFORMANCE 
Page Name -> PM_REVIEW 
Page Qualifier -> FORM_DETAIL
```

Here is a regular expression like  below:

```
perfLogPatternPage = re.compile('(?P<module_id>\w+)\s(?P<page_name>\w+)\s(?P<page_qualifier>\w+)\s\[\[')


print perfLogPatternPage.match(pf_string).group('module_id')
print perfLogPatternPage.match(pf_string).group('page_name')
print perfLogPatternPage.match(pf_string).group('page_qualifier')
```

But this doesn't seem to work and give the right result.

Can someone suggest what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be enough to apply `re.search()` function at once:

```
import re

pf_string = "2018-02-01 00:54:49,285 [210.67.123.00]  [ABC,CDE,sfv4_ABC.,dbPool5,11689563,fp2871,en_US]  UNKNOWN-UNKNOWN EVENT-UNKNOWN-UNKNOWN-pc4bcf46t-20180201005446-663570 2994 770 3199 168 26 [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; ABC-IE11; rv:11.0) like Gecko]     3677610951-0 PERFORMANCE PM_REVIEW FORM_DETAIL [[95211KB 480ms 460ms 20ms 212KB 0KB 118KB 57KB 0 0 ]] 74 139 - - - -   "

m = re.search(r'(?P<module_id>\w+)\s+(?P<page_name>\w+)\s+(?P<page_qualifier>\w+)\s(?=\[\[.)', pf_string)
module_id, page_name, page_qualifier = m.groups()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
pf_string = "2018-02-01 00:54:49,285 [210.67.123.00]  [ABC,CDE,sfv4_ABC.,dbPool5,11689563,fp2871,en_US]  UNKNOWN-UNKNOWN EVENT-UNKNOWN-UNKNOWN-pc4bcf46t-20180201005446-663570 2994 770 3199 168 26 [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; ABC-IE11; rv:11.0) like Gecko]     3677610951-0 PERFORMANCE PM_REVIEW FORM_DETAIL [[95211KB 480ms 460ms 20ms 212KB 0KB 118KB 57KB 0 0 ]] 74 139 - - - -"
results = dict(zip(['Module_id', 'Page Name', 'Page Qualifier'], re.findall('(?<=\-\d)[a-zA-Z\s_]+(?=\[\[\d)', pf_string)[0].split()))
```

Output:

```
{'Module_id': 'PERFORMANCE', 'Page Qualifier': 'FORM_DETAIL', 'Page Name': 'PM_REVIEW'}
```

Comment: pf_string is the variable to store the string.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work. Let me try on few other test strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
\d+-\d+\s+(?P<module_id>[A-Z_]+)\s+(?P<page_name>[A-Z_]+)\s+(?P<page_qualifier>[A-Z_]+)
```

- `\d+-\d+\s+` matches one or more digits, followed by `-`, followed by one or more digits, then one or more spaces
- The each named captured group matches one or more uppercased-alphabetic
  characters or underscore
- The `\s+` in between the captured groups matches one or more spaces

**Example:**

```
In [12]: rcomp = re.compile(r'\d+-\d+\s+(?P<module_id>[A-Z_]+)\s+(?P<page_name>[A-Z_]+)\s+(?P<page_qualifier>[A-Z_]+)')

In [13]: out = rcomp.search(pf_string)

In [14]: out.group('module_id')
Out[14]: 'PERFORMANCE'

In [15]: out.group('page_name')
Out[15]: 'PM_REVIEW'

In [16]: out.group('page_qualifier')
Out[16]: 'FORM_DETAIL'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex requires a few corrections:

- Start from the start of the string (`^`).
- "Consume" three times:

  - A sequence of chars other than `[`.
  - `[` char.
  - A sequence of chars other than `]`.
  - `]` char.
- "Consume" a sequence of spaces (actually *white chars*),
  a sequence of digits or `-` chars and another sequence
  of spaces.
- Then put your 3 named capturing groups, separated with
  a sequence of spaces.

So the whole regex can look like below:

```
^(?:[^\[]+\[[^\]]+\]){3}\s+[-\d]+\s+(?P<module_id>\w+)\s+(?P<page_name>\w+)\s+(?P<page_qualifier>\w+)
```

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/e048Q3/1